# How to set a pattern with timestamp for notification view

Tags: android, view, push-notification, notifications

Im using the `NotificationCompat.Builder` for preparation the notification view. 
The builder interface provides an ability to set timestamp by

```
notificationBuilder.setWhen(remoteMessage.getSentTime());
```

I noticed the platform specific differences of timestamp patterns.

For example:

- Samsung galaxy s8 timestamp pattern "11/12/2013"
- Google pixel 2xl timestamp pattern "now"

Is it possible to provide a custom pattern like DD-MM-YYYY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create yourself a custom layout for your notification, and add there a `TextView` or whatever for your `Timestamp` and then you can assign your layout to your builder.

So initially you can use `RemoteViews` to create your custom layout notification

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.your_custom_notification_layout);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTimestamp, yourDateWithAnyFormat); //You want to create a  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MM-YYYY"); or something
```

Then you add this `RemoteViews` to your `NotificationCompat.Builder` as normal.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContent(contentView); //<-- content View is a RemoteViews that contains your custom layout
```

Let me know if you need further more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Skizo-ozᴉʞS, I thought about it, it's definitely solve the problem, I just feel that it is to much to prepare custom view just to configure timestamp pattern. Might be already exist some sdk method witch I missed out.

Comment: Other thing is create a class that extends the one you want and override that method and change the result with your pattern...

Comment: Any news on this ?